# I Can't Pass Value with Callback Function to Parrent Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

I have two components as named `PaymentForm.tsx` (The parent component) and as named `InputFragment.tsx` (The child component)

I want to pass true or false value with `flag` variable to parent component using via `callback` function. But I can't, how can ı do that? Thanks.

[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlMgg.png)

***PaymentForm.tsx***

```
"use client";
/** 3rd Libraries */
import "../../base/_index.scss";

/** Page Styles */
import "./_payment-form.scss";

/** Components */
import InputFragment from "../html/InputFragment";
import Agreement from "../html/Agreement";

/** TODO
 * 1- improve e-mail pattern 1emin.altan@hotmail.com => Not accept similar format
 * 2- improve name pattern emin03 => Not accept similar format
 * 3- Create error for when input is focused and deactivated.
 */

const PaymentForm = () => {
  var errorLog;

  const getData = (val) => {
    errorLog = val;
    console.log(errorLog);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <InputFragment flag={getData} /> /** Here I want to pass getData function to InputFragment child component.*/
      <div className="payment-form">
        <style>
          @import
          url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap');
        </style>
        <InputFragment
          selector={"input-fragment"}
          labelFor={"name"}
          labelName={"Name:"}
          inputType={"text"}
          defaultValue={"John Doe e.g"}
          min={null}
          max={null}
          minLength={null}
          maxLength={null}
          pattern={"[A-Za-z]"}
        />

        <InputFragment
          selector={"input-fragment"}
          labelFor={"email"}
          labelName={"E-Mail:"}
          inputType={"email"}
          defaultValue={"john@reklamfab.com e.g"}
          min={null}
          max={null}
          minLength={null}
          maxLength={null}
          pattern={"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,}$"}
        />

        <InputFragment
          selector={"input-fragment"}
          labelFor={"phone"}
          labelName={"Phone Number:"}
          inputType={"tel"}
          defaultValue={"0555 555 55 55 e.g"}
          min={null}
          max={null}
          minLength={null}
          maxLength={11}
          pattern={"[0-9]{4} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}"}
        />

        <InputFragment
          selector={"input-fragment"}
          labelFor={"credit-card"}
          labelName={"Credit Card Number:"}
          inputType={"text"}
          defaultValue={"55024xxxx1637489 e.g"}
          min={null}
          max={null}
          minLength={null}
          maxLength={null}
          pattern={"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}"}
        />

        <InputFragment
          selector={"input-fragment input-fragment-min"}
          labelFor={"cvv"}
          labelName={"CVV Number:"}
          inputType={"text"}
          defaultValue={"523 e.g"}
          min={null}
          max={null}
          minLength={null}
          maxLength={3}
          pattern={"[0-9]{3}"}
        />

        <InputFragment
          selector={"input-fragment input-fragment-min"}
          labelFor={"expiry-date"}
          labelName={"Expiry Date:"}
          inputType={"text"}
          defaultValue={"06/10 e.g"}
          min={null}
          max={0}
          minLength={null}
          maxLength={5}
          pattern={"[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}"}
        />

        <InputFragment
          selector={"input-fragment"}
          labelFor={"address"}
          labelName={"Shipment Address:"}
          inputType={"text"}
          defaultValue={"670 S Van Ness Avenue e.g"}
          min={null}
          max={null}
          minLength={null}
          maxLength={null}
          pattern={"[A-Za-z0-9.]"}
        />

        <Agreement />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default PaymentForm;
```

***InputFragment.tsx***

```
// TODO's: If credit card number start witth 5555 show icon mastercard, if card number start witth 4444 show visa car icon.

/** Usage Pattern
 *
 * <InputFragment
 * class={"input-fragment"}
 * labelFor={"name"}
 * labelName={"Name:"}
 * inputType={"text"}
 * defaultValue={"John Doe"}
 * min={null}
 * max={null}
 * minLength={null}
 * maxLength={null}
 * pattern={"[A-Za-z]"}
 * />
 */

/** For client operations */
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import "./_input-fragment.scss";

const InputFragment = ({
  selector,
  labelFor,
  labelName,
  inputType,
  defaultValue,
  min,
  max,
  minLength,
  maxLength,
  pattern,
  size,
  flag,
}) => {
  var [val, setVal] = useState(); /** I'm going to change val variable in error() function */
  // Global variables defination
  const parrentElement = document.getElementsByClassName("input-fragment");
  const inputElement = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  const spanElement = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  let message = document.getElementsByClassName("message");

  // With checkval() function controlled trigger operation for <input> element.
  const checkVal = () => {
    let result;

    // For each <input> element added blur event listener. When <input> element values change, below stack of codes will work.
    for (let i = 0; i < inputElement.length; i++) {
      inputElement[i].addEventListener("blur", () => {
        // When <input> element values not properly entered for type attr error() function will work.
        const error = (errorType) => {
          parrentElement[i].classList.remove("input-fragment-success");
          parrentElement[i].classList.add("input-fragment-error");
          message[i].innerHTML = errorType;
          spanElement[i].classList.add("error");
          spanElement[i].classList.remove("success");
          spanElement[i].classList.remove("none");
          setVal("true");
        };

        // When <input> element values properly entered for type attr success() function will work.
        const success = () => {
          parrentElement[i].classList.remove("input-fragment-error");
          parrentElement[i].classList.add("input-fragment-success");
          message[i].innerHTML = "";

          spanElement[i].classList.add("success");
          spanElement[i].classList.remove("error");
          spanElement[i].classList.remove("none");
        };
        // Get value of <input> element and assing to value variable.
        const value = inputElement[i].value;
        const defaultValue = inputElement[i].defaultValue;

        const checkPattern = (pattern) => {
          if (value.match(pattern)) {
            result = true;
          }
        };

        // Get name of <input> element and assing to inputName variable.
        const inputName = inputElement[i].name;
        // Get pattern of <input> element and assing to inputPattern variable.
        const inputPattern = inputElement[i].pattern;

        // To check value pattern of <input> element with checkPattern() function. <input> element's value will be send checkPattern() function and evulate a result if result consist of <input> element pattern then success() function wil be work. if not error() function will be work.
        checkPattern(inputPattern);

        value === ""
          ? error("This field can't pass empty.")
          : inputName === "name" && (!result || value === defaultValue)
          ? error("Invalid name")
          : inputName === "email" && (!result || value === defaultValue)
          ? error("Invalid e-mail address")
          : inputName == "phone" && (!result || value === defaultValue)
          ? error("Invalid phone number")
          : inputName == "credit-card" && (!result || value === defaultValue)
          ? error("Invalid credit card number")
          : inputName == "cvv" && (!result || value === defaultValue)
          ? error("Invalid credit card number")
          : inputName == "expiry-date" && (!result || value === defaultValue)
          ? error("Invalid expiry date")
          : inputName == "address" && (!result || value === defaultValue)
          ? error("Invalid shipment address")
          : success();
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>{flag(val)}</p> /** Setting up flag variable content with val variable then send to PaymentForm.tsx But I can't do that. I'm appear error message in attachment. */
      <div className={selector}>
        <label htmlFor={labelFor}>
          {labelName}
          <input
            type={inputType}
            defaultValue={defaultValue}
            id={labelFor}
            name={labelFor}
            min={min}
            max={max}
            minLength={minLength}
            maxLength={maxLength}
            size={size}
            pattern={pattern}
            onClick={() => checkVal()}
          />
        </label>
        <span className="none"></span>
      </div>
      <p className="message"></p>
    </>
  );
};
export default InputFragment;
```

Comment: I'm resolved issue. I'm added `flag=getData` prop in each `<InputFragment/>` component and remove `  below line in `PaymentForm` parent component.    

`<InputFragment flag={getData} /> /** Here I want to pass getData function to InputFragment child component.*/`

But I'm open other ideas.
`

Comment: Put this comment as an edit to your question, saying one way to do this is...